# Drawing multiple sprites causes a huge performance issue in Unity

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, rendering

I have about 150 sprites in the scene and the half of them are static and share the same sprite. Now what happens here is that I get about 50 draw calls along with the gui elements and my main camera which draws those sprites cannot draw them without decreasing the performance. I get about 38 fps when I'm supposed to get at least 59 and boy, isn't it significant. The profiler indicates that Main camera has a hard time drawing "Render.TransparentGeometry" which breaks down to 3 more elements, the one with the hightest percentage says "RenderForwardAlpha.Render".

I'm guessing it's because %30 of each sprite is transparent? If that's the case how can I fix it? I mean this engine is not that weak I know there's a way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a good idea to look at atlasses in Unity's "Sprite Packer" to help reduce draw calls: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpritePacker.html